# no duplication in a C code

Tags: c

I want to know why this C code works without any duplication for `p` as it also gets updated, but if i put `w` in `ind_w[i]` it needs duplication?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 132
#define MAXW 30
int Len_w[MAXW];
int Max_V(int vf[], int len);
main()
{
    char s[MAX+1], w[MAXW], *Ind_w[MAXW],*p,out[MAXW];
    int k=0, i=0, Maximum, g=0;
    p=s;
    printf("\nInsert the line....\n");
    fgets(s,MAX,stdin);

    while(sscanf(p,"%s%n",w,&k)==1){
        Len_w[i] = strlen(w);
        Ind_w[i] = p;
        p+=k;
        i++;
    }
    Maximum = Max_V(Len_w,i+1);

    for(g=0;g<=i;g++){
       if(Len_w[g] == Maximum){
           sscanf(Ind_w[g],"%s",out);
           printf("\n%s",out);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int Max_V(int vf[], int len)
{
    int j; int Max=0;
    Max=vf[0];
    for(j=0;j<len;j++)
    {
        if(vf[j]>Max)
        {
            Max=vf[j];
        }
    }
    return Max;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: p is a pointer and w isn't.

Comment: Can you deobfuscate your code before you post it to stack overflow?  Kinda hard to read it with all these different variables assigned only single letter names.

Comment: Um, because p is different each time whereas w is always the same. The first thing that should be taught about C is *the memory model*.

Comment: BTW, the downvotes and, even more so the votes to close, are unwarranted.

Comment: @syb0rg Since the semantics of the program are irrelevant, so are the names of the variables.

Comment: @JimBalter they are most definitely warranted. This post is ridiculously low-quality, the OP didn't have proper code formatting, and it was just a simple 'I can haz teh codes?' question.

Comment: Why even bother to respond if all you're going to do is tell blatant lies? And this is the first time I've ever seen anyone suggest that a question should be closed because the code lacks formatting.

Answer (score 3):

```
p=s;

while(sscanf(p,"%s%n",w,&k)==1){
    Len_w[i] = strlen(w);
    Ind_w[i] = p;
    p+=k;
    i++;
}
```

The pointer to the starting position where `sscanf` writes the scanned word to changes in each call. so the words are stored one after the other in `w`, and the positions where the words start (in the array `s`) are stored in `Ind_w`.

If you store

```
Ind_w[i] = w;
```

you store always the same address, that of the first `char` in `w`.

Comment: p is a char pointer pointing to words so a string of words and w could be considered as a pointer...

Comment: `w` is an array. In most use cases, `w` is converted to `&w[0]`, but while you can make a pointer point to different locations, an array stays put. So `pointer = w;` or `function(w);` will always convert `w` to the same pointer. `p` is a pointer, it points to different places during its lifetime, and storing its value in other pointers stores different addresses at different times.